# Customized access log (Apache Tomcat 7.0.8) remains zero kb

Tags: tomcat-valve

I'm trying to create a shorten/customized version of AccessLog (naming it Stats_log)
to log out few items (HTTP code, response time, request type) from the request.

So i've copied my full AccessLogValve and edited it to match my needs. 
after restarting the server, the new log is created but it remains zero(!) 0kb.

can anyone point out what am I doing wrong here?

The weird thing is that the customized log works for me (using the same settings) in my testing ENV which is running Apache Tomcat 7.0.2. (while the PROD environment is 7.0.8).

Any suggestions?

here are the Valve settings as appear in the server.xml file:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="172.30.21.244_**access_log**." suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" resolveHosts="false"/>

<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_stats_log." suffix=".txt" fileDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd.HH" pattern="%U,%s,%D,%{Internal-Status-Code}o" resolveHosts="false"/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The following actions have resolved this:
1) it seems that my copy & paste somehow added a line brake (\n). 
2) moved the customized AccessLogValve under  to be under .

That's made the trick :)